# Redefine internal toc level

Tags: table-of-contents

Usually the internal level of a heading element is well defined. Part is -1, Chapter is 0, Section is 1 and so on. Currently I'm trying to separate certain parts in the appendix of my document. For this I use the `\part` command. Since the document itself is `scrartcl` the highest level I use is `section`. Within the document the usage of part looks as it should, however, in the table of content it is differently indented and in a larger font size.

An alternative is to define a custom command that creates a part-look-a-like page and manually adds the title parameter to the TOC. However, I'm curious, is there a way to manipulate the internal TOC level of a heading element? For example, change the level of part from -1 to 1. This should result in the behavior that a part is within the table of contents is displayed like a section.

Comment: Would `\makeatletter\let\l@part\l@chapter\makeatother` solve the problem? If so, I'll explain it in an answer. If not, please post a [MWE (link)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) so that we know what is your exact situation.

Comment: @tohecz: `\makeatletter\let\l@part\l@section\makeatother` was my personal solution. l@<HEADING> was the concept I didn't know. Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can convince the Table of Contents that your part is a chapter by putting this into your preamble (or whereever before `\tableofcontents`):

```
\makeatletter \let\l@part\l@chapter \makeatother
```